# .htaccess redirect all requests to non www https domain?

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I know there are a lot of questions on stack overflow regarding this already, but none of the solutions I find seem to work properly.

I have set up an SSL cert that requires the domain it's on to be non-www.

I want to redirect a user visiting my site to https://example.com no matter where they are coming from:

`http://example.com` becomes `https://example.com`

`http://www.example.com` becomes `https://example.com`

`https://www.example.com` becomes `https://example.com`

Should be simple but unfortunately I have no .htaccess knowledge. I appreciate any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this code in your `DOCUMENT_ROOT/.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off [OR]
RewriteCond ^www\. [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://example.com%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,NE,L]
```

Comment: This rules are working proper without sub directory, but when you add subdirectory, case https://www.example.com/LineDemo. Let me know you can resolve this issue and update htaccess rule

Comment: This rule has nothing to do with a sub directory. You may have some other issue. Please open a new question with details and I will try to answer.

Comment: Thanks Anubhava for quick reply but I have resolved it with help of this article, https://simonecarletti.com/blog/2016/08/redirect-domain-http-https-www-apache/

Answer (score 0):

Below ruleset is fulfilling all below 6 cases:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\. [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:www\.)?(.+)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://%1%{REQUEST_URI} [L,NE,R=301]


Cases: 
C1: http://example.com/
C2: http://www.example.com/
C3: https://www.example.com/

C4: http://example.com/LineDemo/
C5: http://www.example.com/LineDemo/
C6: https://www.example.com/LineDemo/
```